# AWS license manager: is it possible to uncheck-out instillment?

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to [this documentationn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/license-manager/latest/userguide/seller-issued-licenses.html), you can create seller-issued licenses that will be used by customers who purchased your license. To declare right on the license the customer launches your software which in its turn checks out the license entitlement and that's how you track your license usage.

But is it possible to uncheck-out entitlement if the machine with your software becomes broken or stolen? Or is there an update API (to change for example Node ID) and then on the new machine (new) you should use the same consumption token that you acquired the first time?